# Possible to use netbook as wireless device for Desktop pc?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

My desktop computer has problem on external wireless device so i want to  use my netbook as wireless device for desktop computer.

Is this possible ? if so how can i do this ?

Edit: Both machines has windows 7 installed.

Comment: Windows or linux laptop?  It is possible in both just answer will vary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can share your physical nic port with another computer.  Get the laptop onto wireless and in windows you can do this fairly easily by right clicking on your wired device and clicking share.

I used to do this with my xbox 360 when a cable was not reachable to the router, worked like a charm.

- [Sharing internet in windows 7/Vista](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Using-ICS-Internet-Connection-Sharing)

  - to my knowledge 7/vista are identical
- [Sharing internet in XP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306126)

Comment: Can you specify steps and details ?